# 2nd floor balcony Help

Tags: deck, balcony

Recently open a couple of wood board on my 2nd floor balcony and found the pictures below.

https://imgur.com/a/GQLQ5PR

Not sure how to go about making this good again. A bit concern around the water pooling at the bottom there.

We bought the place a couple of months ago and just got around to fixing this balcony now.

Comment: Check under the balcony for drain holes.  Water pooling at the house means the drain holes are blocked, or worst the balcony as raised up at the outside, so water is flowing towards the house/not flowing away.

Comment: How big is the patio?

Comment: Yeah that's no good. Pull the entire deck and show me the roof. It's either not pitched right, or your sleepers are now 'grouted' by debris and retaining water. When you put the deck boards back, flip them over for the 'new' good side.